# Why no one has answer for java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0.0' as the

Tags: unix, katalon-studio

In my local Unix Ubuntu env I keep getting an error as

```
java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.
```

I tried all the below options

1)-Djava.awt.headless

2) installed xvbf.

3) export DISPLAY=:0.0

I also gave command line as

```
./katalon -runMode=console -projectPath="/home/jenktran/Automation/Katalon First Proj/Katalon First Proj.prj" -retry=0 -testSuitePath="Test Suites/TimesheetTestCaseForChrome" -browserType="Chrome (headless)"

./katalon -runMode=console -projectPath="/home/jenktran/Automation/Katalon First Proj/Katalon First Proj.prj" -retry=0 -testSuitePath="Test Suites/TimesheetTestCaseForChrome" -browserType="Chrome (headless)" ---Djava.awt.headless
```

What else i can do?

Comment: Have you resolved? i've the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Try the command 
**$xhost +**
This will disable the access control and allows any client to connect